# send Content-Type: application/json post with node.js

Tags: node.js, post, curl

How can we make a HTTP request like this in NodeJS? Example or module appreciated.

```
curl https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{"longUrl": "http://www.google.com/"}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) is Lesser and Better:**

```
const data = JSON.stringify({
  message: 'Hello World!'
})

const url = "https://localhost/WeatherAPI";

axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url, 
    data: JSON.stringify(data), 
    headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}
}) 
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(`statusCode: ${res.status}`)
    console.log(res)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error)
  })
```

Also check **5 Ways to Make HTTP Requests in Node.js**

https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/http-requests-in-node-js.html

**Refer:**

https://nodejs.dev/learn/make-an-http-post-request-using-nodejs

https://flaviocopes.com/node-http-post/

https://stackabuse.com/making-asynchronous-http-requests-in-javascript-with-axios/

Answer (score 296):

[**Mikeal's request**](https://github.com/mikeal/request) module can do this easily:

```
var request = require('request');

var options = {
  uri: 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url',
  method: 'POST',
  json: {
    "longUrl": "http://www.google.com/"
  }
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body.id) // Print the shortened url.
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this helpful answer. In the end I realize the option is well documented. But lost in the middle of plenty others...

Comment: It didn't worked for me until i added the `headers: {'content-type' : 'application/json'},` option.

Comment: - the NodeJs 'request' module is deprecated.
- how would we do this using 'http' module ?

Thank you.

Comment: **Axios is Lesser and Better:** , Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67492793/2218697) post.

Answer (score 12):

**Simple Example**

```
var request = require('request');

//Custom Header pass
var headersOpt = {  
    "content-type": "application/json",
};
request(
        {
        method:'post',
        url:'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url', 
        form: {name:'hello',age:25}, 
        headers: headersOpt,
        json: true,
    }, function (error, response, body) {  
        //Print the Response
        console.log(body);  
});
```

Answer (score 12):

As the [official documentation](https://github.com/request/request) says:

> body - entity body for PATCH, POST and PUT requests. Must be a Buffer, String or ReadStream. If json is true, then body must be a JSON-serializable object.

When sending JSON you just have to put it in body of the option.

```
var options = {
    uri: 'https://myurl.com',
    method: 'POST',
    json: true,
    body: {'my_date' : 'json'}
}
request(options, myCallback)
```

Comment: Is it just me or its documentation sucks?

Answer (score 4):

For some reason only this worked for me today. All other variants ended up in *bad json* error from API.

Besides, yet another variant for creating required POST request with JSON payload.

```js
request.post({
    uri: 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify({"longUrl": "http://www.google.com/"})
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the `request` module that other answers use has been deprecated, may I suggest switching to `node-fetch`:

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch")

const url = "https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url"
const payload = { longUrl: "http://www.google.com/" }

const res = await fetch(url, {
  method: "post",
  body: JSON.stringify(payload),
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
})

const { id } = await res.json()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using request with headers and post.

```
var options = {
            headers: {
                  'Authorization': 'AccessKey ' + token,
                  'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
            },
            uri: 'https://myurl.com/param' + value',
            method: 'POST',
            json: {'key':'value'}
 };
      
 request(options, function (err, httpResponse, body) {
    if (err){
         console.log("Hubo un error", JSON.stringify(err));
    }
    //res.status(200).send("Correcto" + JSON.stringify(body));
 })
```