# Node JS Coinbase Pro API {invalid signature}

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been trying to build a script that does a POST request to Coinbase Pro, using the details on their dev forum and api.

I have based it on one of their dev's code that posted a GET request which works just fine.

Here's my code:

```js
const config = require('dotenv').config();
var crypto = require('crypto');
const https = require('https');

// current unix timestamp in seconds (note Date.now() returns milliseconds)
var cb_access_timestamp = Date.now() / 1000;

// obtained API key, secret, and passphrase from https://pro.coinbase.com/profile/api
var cb_access_passphrase = process.env.cb_access_passphrase;
var cb_api_key = process.env.cb_api_key;
var cb_secret = process.env.cb_secret;
var path = '/orders';
//var body = '';
var body = JSON.stringify({
  product_id: "BTC-USD",
  side: "buy",
  type: "limit",
  size: "0.0001",
  price: "40151.51"
});

var method = 'POST';

// create the prehash string by concatenating required parts
var message = cb_access_timestamp + method + path + body;

// decode the base64 secret
// NOTE: added .from() to address DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated
var key = Buffer.from(cb_secret, 'base64');
// create a sha256 hmac with the secret
var hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', key);
// sign the required message with the hmac, and finally base64 encode the result
var sign = hmac.update(message).digest('base64');

const options = {
  //hostname: 'api.exchange.coinbase.com',
  hostname: 'api.pro.coinbase.com',
  port: 443,
  path: path,
  method: method,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Content-Length': 0,
    'User-Agent': 'MyTradingBot',
    'CB-ACCESS-KEY': cb_api_key,
    'CB-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE': cb_access_passphrase,
    'CB-ACCESS-SIGN': sign,
    'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP': cb_access_timestamp
  },
  body: body
}

const req = https.request(options, res => {
  console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)

  res.on('data', d => {
    process.stdout.write(d)
  })
})

req.on('error', error => {
  console.error(error)
})

req.end()
```

The response is:

```
statusCode: 401
{"message":"invalid signature"}
```

If I leave the body empty the response I get is that the product_id is invalid, meaning that it connects to the api, but expects the parameters for the body.

Comment: check out the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67100813/1308285. It is for sandbox but it's working code

Comment: Super. Thank you so much for finding that gem. It actually works great on the production API. Confirmed!

Comment: I wrote that piece so please upvote if you found it useful :)

Comment: I was talking about that answer stackoverflow.com/a/67100813/1308285 you can upvote it.